# PHP MYSQL - Echo mysql value containing a PHP variable?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I am trying to get a variable to display, when used as part of a value inside of a mysql table.

```
$variable = 'cool';

MYSQL FIELD VALUE

"This is '.$variable.' wow"
```

When i echo this value, it displays as:

```
This is '.$variable.' wow
```

I want it to display as:

```
This is cool wow
```

What is the trick here?

@Mark sorry im new to this

```
$linkQuery3 = 'SELECT model
FROM models
WHERE model_id = "'.$pageModel.'"
';
$sql15 = mysql_query($linkQuery3) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($sql15) == 0) {
    die('No results.');
} else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql15)) {
     $model = stripslashes($row['model']);
    }
}

$linkQuery2 = 'SELECT l.link , l.desc , l.domId , d.domain FROM links l INNER JOIN domains d ON d.domId = l.domId WHERE l.catId="'.$pageCat.'" && (l.modId="1" || l.modId="'.$pageModel.'") ORDER BY domain
';
$sql3 = mysql_query($linkQuery2) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($sql3) == 0) {
    die('No results.');
} else {
    $pageContent .= '';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3)) {
     $linkAd = ($row['link']);
     $linkDesc = ($row['desc']);
     $linkDomain = ($row['domain']);
     $pageContent .= '
        <li><a href="'.$linkAd.'" target="_tab">'.$linkDesc.' '.$linkDomain.'</a></li>
    ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your quote marks are mismatched.  Try setting the db value to "This is ".$variable." wow"

Comment: tried this and displays as ".$variable." quotes are like that because echo'd field is displayed within another variable, by chance has it got something to do with some kind of declaration? like htmlspecialchars

Comment: @Mark alright thanks for the edit, that was driving me crazy. What i am trying to do is get the value of `$model` to show up in the value of the `desc` field when `$linkDesc` is echo'd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing here is trying to echo the string from the database, but replace placeholder text with a specific value. You cannot do this by just storing a string that the PHP parser would treat in a specific way, and expect PHP to treat it the same way when it sees that string at run-time.

Here is what I suggest: Use a more straightforward delimiter for the part of the string you wish to replace, like so:

```
"This is :variable: wow"
```

and use `str_replace()` to echo the right thing. (You can also use `sprintf()` for the same purpose.)

```
echo str_replace(':variable:', $variable, $mystring);
```

(Here `$mystring` contains the string from the database.)

Comment: sounds like we're both on the same page here, let me let this info soak in and i'll let you know :) thank you!

Comment: how would str_replace work in this case? `$linkAd = ($row['link']);` the variable is inside of a value in the field `link`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you saying that you want to retrieve the column `link` and replace a placeholder that appears within? Just use `$linkAd = str_replace(':variable:', $variable, $row['link'])`. Or are you saying that you want to use the value of `link` to perform the substitution? Use `echo str_replace(':variable:', $row['link'], $mystring)`.

Answer (score 2):

use double quotes :

```
echo "This is " . $variable . " wow";
```

Comment: displays as " . $variable . "

Comment: OP has the string as literal text in his database. echoing a variable containing the string does not magically make it be treated as PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval) the string you retrieve from MySQL. There's no other way of getting a string to be interpreted as PHP code. eval() should be avoided at all costs, however. You'd be better off using a templating system, or a simple string-substitution system, than eval()ing stuff coming out of a database.

Comment: This is correct. +1.  Another question would be, why are you storing the **variable** in the database?  Shouldn't you store the variable contents in the database and reverse the way you're storing/displaying things?

Comment: I don't see a reason to suggest `eval()` here, when nothing in the OP suggests he wants to do anything other than echo parameterised strings.

Comment: eval() expects valid JS code. You'd need to do `$var = 'cool'; $string = 'This is $var'; eval("\$newstring = '$string'");`. But again, eval() is evil. You're not doing simple string substitution, you're trying to write a whole new PHP script on the fly. It's a bad idea. use str_replace() and the like instead.

Comment: @Hammerite: yes, but OP is doing `INSERT INTO table (x) VALUES ('This is $variable')`, so that the literal word `$variable` is in the database. There's no way to get the retrieved string to be interpreted and `$varaible` substituted with its value without eval, unless you want to do `str_replace($string, '$variable', 'cool');`

Comment: See the variable contents are in the database "$model = stripslashes($row['model']);" This is why its a little more complicated than my example. I was thinking stripslashes needs to be replaced, as said, by a directive saying that the field `link` contains php code being $model?

Comment: please check out this page, http://www.free4blackberry.com/downloads/9800/apps.php at the very bottom you will see a list of links,number seven link from the bottom you will see what i am working with.

Comment: @Mark What im trying to do is get a value from a seperate field in another table to display inside of the value in this field on this table. Eval sounds like its exactly what i need, but it breaks my pages to peices :(

Comment: @Mark `$linkQuery3 = 'SELECT model
FROM models
WHERE model_id = "'.$pageModel.'"
';

$sql15 = mysql_query($linkQuery3) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($sql15) == 0) {
 die('No results.');
} else {
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql15)) {
  $model = stripslashes($row['model']);
 }
}`

Comment: Don't stuff code into comments. modify your question and put it up top.

Comment: @Mark `$linkQuery2 = 'SELECT l.link , l.desc , l.domId , d.domain FROM links l INNER JOIN domains d ON d.domId = l.domId WHERE l.catId="'.$pageCat.'" && (l.modId="1" || l.modId="'.$pageModel.'") ORDER BY domain
';

$sql3 = mysql_query($linkQuery2) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($sql3) == 0) {
 die('No results.');
} else {
 $pageContent .= '';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3)) {
 $linkAd = ($row['link']);
 $linkDesc = ($row['desc']);
 $linkDomain = ($row['domain']);
 $pageContent .= '
     <li><a href="'.$linkAd.'" target="_tab">'.$linkDesc.' '.$linkDomain.'</a></li>
 ';
 }
}`

Comment: @Mark I want `$model` to show inside of the value in the `desc` field when $linkDesc is echo'd

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"This is '" . $variable . '" wow"
```

Comment: displays as '" . $variable . '"

Answer (score 0):

This can be a heck of a lot simpler. Just do this...

```
echo "This is '$variable' wow";
```

That is all you need. There is no need to leave the string context and come back in. The outer double-quotes will evaluate the value of a variable. If you had used single quotes on the outside then it would be evaluated literally as $variable and not its value.

So you would write a select statement like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fancytbl WHERE id = '$id' AND myhands = 'diamonds'";
```

See, its simple.

Comment: its more complicated than my little example i promise :) the basic idea is there though.